# Reduce opacity of base terrain to "see through" mountains in 3D

Tags: 3d, opacity, mapbox-gl, terrain

How to change opacity of base DEM terrain in 3D? I applied an empty style and yet the mountains hide the trace (a layer containing a geoJSON LineString).

I would like to change the terrain base layer or additional layers to partially see through the terrain, see the road behind the mountain, but it seems that event the empty style still is 100% opaque.

Is there a way to change the opacity of the base terrain?

The setup:

```
  const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: "map",
    zoom: 11.53,
    center: [6.5615, 46.0598],
    pitch: 65,
    bearing: -180,
    style: "mapbox://styles/francoisvk/cksyxgwzb2hut17p52jno45tl",    
    interactive: true
  });

    map.addSource("mapbox-dem", {
      type: "raster-dem",
      url: "mapbox://mapbox.mapbox-terrain-dem-v1",
      tileSize: 512,
      maxzoom: 14
    });
    map.setTerrain({ source: "mapbox-dem", exaggeration: 1.5 });

    map.addSource("trace", {
      type: "geojson",
      data: {
        type: "Feature",
        properties: {},
        geometry: {
          type: "LineString",
          coordinates: targetRoute
        }
      }
    });

    map.addLayer({
      type: "line",
      source: "trace",
      id: "line",
      paint: {
        "line-color": "orange",
        "line-width": 4
      },
      layout: {
        "line-cap": "round",
        "line-join": "round"
      }
    });
```

The empty / blank style:

```
{
"version": 8,
"name": "OutdoorsEmpty",
"metadata": {
    "mapbox:type": "default",
    "mapbox:origin": "outdoors-v11",
    "mapbox:sdk-support": {
        "android": "9.3.0",
        "ios": "5.10.0",
        "js": "2.3.0"
    },
    "mapbox:autocomposite": true,
    "mapbox:uiParadigm": "components",
    "mapbox:groups": {}
},
"center": [-112.966918, 37.270007],
"zoom": 15.9,
"bearing": 0,
"pitch": 0,
"sources": {},
"sprite": "mapbox://sprites/francoisvk/cksyxgwzb2hut17p52jno45tl/draft",
"glyphs": "mapbox://fonts/mapbox/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
"layers": [],
"created": "2021-08-30T17:40:53.908Z",
"modified": "2021-08-31T06:45:26.704Z",
"id": "cksyxgwzb2hut17p52jno45tl",
"owner": "francoisvk",
"visibility": "private",
"draft": true
}
```

The rendering where the mountain hides the road.

[image]